# Alternative to GPT type transformers for non NL based input

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, reinforcement-learning, transformers

Using a GPT or similar transformer I can feed it a string of text and essentially request a summary. From my experience this works pretty well. However I've not found any similar model or transformer that take a non natural language input and can output a summary. The closest thing I can think of is a algorithm that describes what is happening in an image - which doesn't quite seem like the right task (eg, if it's a *massive* image I won't want a description of everything that happening, just a summary).

Is there a type of model that works like this? Eg. A model that takes any type of input (presented as a vector, matrix or tensor) and summarises the input into natural language?

More detail:
I realised as I wrote this that I would need to explain a little more. Obviously I would need to give the model a set of training data based on my specific inputs and expected outputs, however doing so from scratch would typically take an unreasonably large dataset for a NLP task. Are there pretrained models of this type?

Answer (score 1):

> A model that takes any type of input (presented as a vector, matrix or
> tensor) and summarises the input into natural language?

There are for sure models which do image captioning, video captioning, text summarization, etc. You can of course write some wrapper code which runs one of many models depending on the input modality, enabling it to summarize anything at all.

Just to make it clear -- I don't think it's a reasonable idea to have a *monolithic* model which directly ingests a raw byte-stream and outputs natural language -- even the human brain doesn't work that way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Could you point me to some of the models that do this that I could perhaps reperpose?

Comment: here are some survey papers https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04020.pdf https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.00186.pdf